# An error in actionPerformed method

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        Label l = new Label("Sam");
        Button b = new Button("Click me");
        Label l2 = new Label();

        l.setBounds(3,5,4000,5000);
        l.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        b.setLocation(5,5);
        b.setSize(1,1);


        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500,600);
        f.setResizable(false);

        p.add(l);
        p.add(b);
        p.setBackground(Color.red);


        f.add(p);

        b.addActionListener(this);

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String str = e.getActionCommand();

            if(str.equals("Click me"))
                System.out.println("GM");

        }
    }
}
```

In this why Intellij is showing an error in actionPerformed method .

They showing error in the declaration of ActionEvent e .

**Error:**

[image: Error]

Please help me, I am a beginner.

Also is this correct : b.addActionListener(this); ?

Answer (score 1):

Move `actionPerformed()` method out of `main()` method.

Comment: But why ? Can you please explain the reason .

Comment: Also is this correct : b.addActionListener(this); ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    ....
    b.addActionListener(this);

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String str = e.getActionCommand();

        if(str.equals("Click me"))
            System.out.println("GM");

    }
}
```

Should be

```
    ....
    b.addActionListener(new Main());

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String str = e.getActionCommand();
    if(str.equals("Click me"))
        System.out.println("GM");
}
```

You have defined a method inside another method, which is illegal in Java.

Based on your code, `new Main()` is fine. However, it isn't the best way. A better implementation would be as follows:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        Label l = new Label("Sam");
        Button b = new Button("Click me");
        Label l2 = new Label();

        l.setBounds(3,5,4000,5000);
        l.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        b.setLocation(5,5);
        b.setSize(1,1);


        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500,600);
        f.setResizable(false);

        p.add(l);
        p.add(b);
        p.setBackground(Color.red);


        f.add(p);

        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener{
            @Override 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String str = e.getActionCommand();

                if(str.equals("Click me"))
                System.out.println("GM");

             }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Then it is showing error for " b.addActionListener(this); "
That is : 
 java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 0):

- you should use a constructor
- your main should contain object(s)

public class main implements ActionListener {

```
main(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    Label l = new Label("Sam");
    Button b = new Button("Click me");
    Label l2 = new Label();

    l.setBounds(3,5,4000,5000);
    l.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

    b.setLocation(5,5);
    b.setSize(1,1);



    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(500,600);
    f.setResizable(false);

    p.add(l);
    p.add(b);
    p.setBackground(Color.red);


    f.add(p);
    f.setVisible(true);
    b.addActionListener(this);
}



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String str = e.getActionCommand();

    if(str.equals("Click me"))
        System.out.println("GM");

}
```

public static void main(String[] args) {
     main obj = new main();

```
}
```

}